# Application insights integration with AKS

Tags: .net, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a requirement where I need to integrate application insights with AKS. I have multiple microservices which are function apps deployed to an AKS cluster. The function apps are implemented in.net 6 core. I tried the steps mentioned in the link below. But I am still not able to see any logs sent to application insights.

https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Kubernetes/blob/develop/examples/WorkerExample/Readme.md

Packages included are-

```
<ItemGroup>

        <!-- 
            <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.21.0" />
         -->

        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Kubernetes" Version="6.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />


        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.17.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="7.0.1" />

    </ItemGroup>
```

Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Test.Azure.Functions.Articles.Config;
using System;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Test.Azure.Functions.Telemetry;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]

namespace Test.Azure.Functions.Articles.Config
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            if (builder == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
            }


            builder.Services.AddSingleton(s =>
            {
               // var configuration = s.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
                var telemetryConfiguration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
                telemetryConfiguration.InstrumentationKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; //configuration["INSTRUMENT_KEY"]
                var telemetryClient=new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);
                telemetryClient.TrackEvent("AKS_Function_APP_Event");

                return telemetryClient;
            });

            // Add the Application Insights ServiceOptions
            //builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
           //builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsKubernetesEnricher(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Debug);

            // Add the KubernetesTelemetryInitializer to the telemetry initializers
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, KubernetesTelemetryInitializer>();


            builder.Services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
            {
                loggingBuilder.AddApplicationInsights();
            });


            /* builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
             builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsKubernetesEnricher(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Debug);
             builder.Services.AddHostedService<Worker>();*/

        }
    }
}
```

TeleMetryInitializer.cs

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

namespace Test.Azure.Functions.Telemetry
{
    public class KubernetesTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        private const string KubernetesPodNameEnvVar = "HOSTNAME";
        private const string KubernetesPodNamespaceEnvVar = "MY_POD_NAMESPACE";

        private readonly string _podName;
        private readonly string _podNamespace;

        public KubernetesTelemetryInitializer()
        {
            _podName = GetEnvironmentVariable(KubernetesPodNameEnvVar);
            _podNamespace = "microservices-dev"; //GetEnvironmentVariable(KubernetesPodNamespaceEnvVar);
        }

        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleInstance))
            {
                telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleInstance = _podName;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName))
            {
                telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName = _podNamespace;
            }
        }

        private static string GetEnvironmentVariable(string name)
        {
            return System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name, System.EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        }
    }
}
```

When I don't see the telemetry client sending any data to app insights. Also, enabling worker services throws runtime error. Any help would be great. Thank you.

Container Logs-

```
[Information] [2023-03-10T07:34:29.6231734Z] Skip registering K8sInfoBackgroundService by user configuration.
[Debug] [2023-03-10T07:34:29.6249154Z] Application Insights Kubernetes injected the service successfully.
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /azure-functions-host
Now listening on: http://[::]:80
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Host.Triggers.Warmup[0]
      Initializing Warmup Extension.
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Host.Startup[503]
      Initializing Host. OperationId: '0781d31c-7125-4b35-bbeb-d1f528a76f2b'.
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Host.Startup[504]
      Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=1, StartupCount=1, OperationId=0781d31c-7125-4b35-bbeb-d1f528a76f2b
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      LoggerFilterOptions
      {
        "MinLevel": "None",
        "Rules": [
          {
            "ProviderName": null,
            "CategoryName": null,
            "LogLevel": null,
            "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
          },
          {
            "ProviderName": null,
            "CategoryName": "Chevron",
            "LogLevel": "Information",
            "Filter": null
          },
          {
            "ProviderName": null,
            "CategoryName": "Host.Function.ToolingConsoleLog",
            "LogLevel": "Information",
            "Filter": null
          },
          {
            "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
            "CategoryName": null,
            "LogLevel": "None",
            "Filter": null
          },
          {
            "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
            "CategoryName": null,
            "LogLevel": null,
            "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
          }
        ]
      }
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      ConcurrencyOptions
      {
        "DynamicConcurrencyEnabled": false,
        "MaximumFunctionConcurrency": 500,
        "CPUThreshold": 0.8,
        "SnapshotPersistenceEnabled": true
      }
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      FunctionResultAggregatorOptions
      {
        "BatchSize": 1000,
        "FlushTimeout": "00:00:30",
        "IsEnabled": true
      }
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      SingletonOptions
      {
        "LockPeriod": "00:00:15",
        "ListenerLockPeriod": "00:01:00",
        "LockAcquisitionTimeout": "10675199.02:48:05.4775807",
        "LockAcquisitionPollingInterval": "00:00:05",
        "ListenerLockRecoveryPollingInterval": "00:01:00"
      }
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Host.General[337]
      Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000002C83BEC4'.
```

Error while debugging in Visual studio-

```
[2023-03-11T08:28:14.976Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation '22b81d60-dbcc-4a99-a88a-4cb968081c94'.
[2023-03-11T08:28:14.978Z] TestPOC-AF: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: enabling worker services using `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService` is the way to go. What runtime error do you get?

Comment: After adding the telemetry worker service, the function host is not running. Added container logs for reference.

Comment: What is the runtime exception you get? And where did you put the application insights connection string / instrumentation key?

Comment: I have added that in startup.cs. Below is the code. I have masked instrument key.

telemetryConfiguration.InstrumentationKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; //configuration["INSTRUMENT_KEY"]

Comment: Exception-
PS C:\test> kubectl -n test-poc exec -it sleep-84549b8696-pdzh8 -- curl -s function-app

"Function host is not running"


I am trying to call the function app API from another POD under the same namespace

Comment: The error that I see while debugging function app in visual studio-
[2023-03-11T08:28:14.976Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation '22b81d60-dbcc-4a99-a88a-4cb968081c94'.
[2023-03-11T08:28:14.978Z] PMMIPOC-AF: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.